# Intellisense after VS 2012 update 2 insane slow

Tags: visual-studio-2012, intellisense, updates

After updating my VS 2012 to the **update 2,** while working in a XAML Editor, I have to wait about **2 seconds** for each key. The difference is only if I press CTRL + SPACE, when the Intellisense window appears, than I can write normally. 
In praxis, it looks like I have to press CTRL + SPACE before each property / control. Simply everywhere. It never hapenned in update 1

Answer (score 0):

U know what, after fighting with it and suspecting the properties window to be responsible for the reaction speed, I finally decided to **unistall update 2** and everything works like a charm.